# How to convert a grafana panel's query field value from a decimal number to ASCII digits?

Tags: grafana

I have a grafana (v10.2.2) panel with a query. The query datasource is an influxDB instance.
An example of a field value the query delivers is 12360 which represents ASCII characters:
12360 = 0x3048 -> 0x30 and 0x48 which are ASCII characters '0' and 'H'

How to convert 12360 into "0H" in grafana?

I tried to use the Transform tab of the panel but could not find a suitable transformation in the offered set.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is now way to do what you describe "out of the box" in Grafana.

You can either do this entirely on the data source side (I don't know if that's possible in flux).

Or you can [write your own panel plugin](https://grafana.com/developers/plugin-tools/), to represent data with any required level of customization.